# Check if route can be identify using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a route where I send optional parameters inside it. When I send the last parameter without the others, laravel can not identify the route and displays `404 error page` (not found).

```
Route::get('example/{num?}/{from?}/{to?}', [\App\Http\Controllers\exampleController::class, 'example']);
```

Could you help me to find a solution?

Comment: what URL are you visiting?

Comment: In this case, you can define a route in the form Route::get('example', [\App\Http\Controllers\exampleController::class,'example'])); , So passing values through query string. Line: `http://localhost/example?num=&from=&to=2021`

Comment: thanks, It works when I passed the values via query string

Comment: Please give an example of the URL that return 404 error.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/example//2021-07-14/2021-07-08